# Save and load elements from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, load, save, popcornjs

I have in my webpage a series of elements, for example videos or other media:

```
<div id = "text">
</div>
<video height="240" width="412" id="video" controls="controls"> </video>
```

I change with JavaScript the original status of these elements and I use
Popcorn.js for create a synchronization events, for example:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.src = $("#url").val(); //Change src value
var popcorn = Popcorn( "#video" ); 
popcorn.footnote({ //Create a synchronization event; I add a footnote
start: 2,
stop: 5,
text: 'Hello World!!!',
target: 'text',
});
```

So now, my problem is that I want save these elements with their events.
And after I want to have the possibility to load (in the my webpage) this elements for continue to change them again.
How can I save/load in this case?